# Syntax error while trying to make a route function Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes

I am trying to make a function for routes. but I get a syntax error. The error is:

Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:..../router/index.js: Unexpected token (22:28)

This is my code:

```
function route (path, view, name) {
  return {
    name: name || view,
    path,
    component: (resolve) => import(
      `../views/${view}.vue`
    ).then(resolve)
  }
}
```

The syntax error is on "import". line 5. What is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Can you show the line of the error?

Comment: It is in line 5: "component: (resolve) => import(" The "import" word is the cause of the error

Comment: try replacing `(resolve) => import("...").then(resolve)` for `() => import("...")`. Not sure what you are trying to do with the `then`

Comment: thanks but still I get the same error. I think the problem is somehow related to "import" since it says that "import" is an unexpected token

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the syntax. Use `yarn` instead of `npm`, does it work then? If so, your issue is [already discussed at length here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3335)

Comment: I used `yarn` instead of `npm` still the same issue